# VBA - Inserting Check to Validate Correct File is being Selected

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

In the code below I'm looking to implement a check that verifies the correct file is being selected before executing the rest of the code. Once the 'combinedbook' is open a check will be carried out that verifies certain text is in a certain cell within the workbook. For example, in the code below I need the check to verify that the text "Cash Split" is contained in cell B2 in the combinedWorkbook before carrying out the vlookup and if not to stop executing the code and provide a warning message box.

```
Sub ImportWriteOffs()

Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim combinedFilename As String
Dim combinedWorkbook As Workbook

' Open BRAM Report Source Data

MsgBox ("Select 'SRMF0035'")

filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
caption = "Select 'SRMF0035'"
combinedFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

If combinedFilename <> "False" Then

    Set combinedWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(combinedFilename)

Else

    MsgBox "No file was uploaded", vbExclamation

GoTo LastLine

End If

' Conduct Vlookup on BRAM Report

Dim lastRow As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input Write Offs")

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("B9:B" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = _
                       "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[" & combinedWorkbook.Name & "]Tabular Version'!R10C2:R700000C56,55,0)"

combinedWorkbook.Close False

End With


LastLine:

End Sub
```

Many thanks,
Kieran

Comment: `If combinedWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = "Cash Split" Then` should work.

Answer (score 0):

What you just need to do here is to have an additional conditional statement to check first if the cell("B2") contained the certain text that you want.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input Write Offs")

lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
If .range("B2") = "Cash Split" Then
.Range("B9:B" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = _
                   "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[" & combinedWorkbook.Name & "]Tabular Version'!R10C2:R700000C56,55,0)"
   combinedWorkbook.Close False
Else:
   Msgbox "Display Prompt In Here"
   combinedWorkbook.Close False   'To Ensure that the workbook will be close before ending the routine.
   exit sub
End if

End With
```